# cron tab job not getting executed

Tags: hadoop, cron, hdfs

I have hadoop installed on centOS system. I have a shell script which merges all the small files of HDFS generated at some particular hour folder location into one single file at another location at hdfs.
The shell works perfectly OK when invoked.

I then placed the shell to run as a cron job at 01:30 AM everyday.

I typed `crontab -e` and pasted this:

```
30 1 * * * /home/hadoop/tmp/cron-merge-files.sh > /home/hadoop/tmp/cron-merge-files.txt
```

But the merge operation does not happen. I see at `/var/log/cron` file that at 01:30 AM this entry comes but I cant see those files merged at hdfs. When I simply execute
the shell script, then it works perfectly OK and does the said operation written inside the script.

```
Jul  8 01:30:01 ip-10-1-3-111 CROND[2265463]: (hadoopuser) CMD (/home/hadoop/tmp/cron-merge-files.sh > /home/hadoop/tmp/cron-merge-files.txt)
```

The content of /home/hadoop/tmp/cron-merge-files.txt is a single echo statement which is written inside a loop. The loop is supposed to run 24 times, and it prints it
24 times.

I am not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this problem from another forum. There was some problem with the environment variables not getting picked up when same script was run through crontab. Just exported .bash_profile to my script and it worked.